# know if user have record in week in mysql

Tags: mysql, database

i need help with this i try to think about resolve this but i cant find how resolve with mysql, I need if the users have record in the week, and show this result with this form:

```
       |  user 1  |  user 2  |  user 3
week 1 |    YES   |   NO     |   YES
week 2 |    YES   |   YES    |   NO
week 3 |    YES   |   NO     |   YES
week 4 |    NO    |   YES    |   YES
week 5 |    YES   |   NO     |   NO
week 6 |    YES   |   NO     |   YES
```

I have table users and other table data

```
Table data have: 
-id_user
-info
-date (datetime)

Table users
-id
-name
```

Thanks so muh for help me!!

Answer (score 0):

You've got two things in a row to do here.

1. Summarize your `data` table by week.
2. Pivot your summary so rows appear as columns.

First, to group by week you need an expression that will take a `DATETIME` value and reduce it to a distinct week. If you're working over end-of-year boundaries, the easiest way is a TRUNCATE operation that converts any timestamp to the first day of the week in which it occurs.

```
FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(`date`) -MOD(TO_DAYS(`date`) -1, 7))
```

does that, yielding the preceding Sunday for any date.  If your weeks start on Mondays, substitute `-2` for `-1`.

Using that to do a summary, you get this:

```
SELECT FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(`date`) -MOD(TO_DAYS(`date`) -1, 7)) week_beginning,
       id_user
  FROM `data`
 GROUP BY FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(`date`) -MOD(TO_DAYS(`date`) -1, 7)), id_user
```

Then you need to pivot that result set. Pivoting is a notorious pain in MySQL. This should do the trick if you know the columns you want for users. This takes advantage of the fact that `SUM(boolean)` adds up the number of times `boolean` comes out true.

```
SELECT week_beginning, 
       CASE SUM(users.user = 'user_1') WHEN 0 THEN 'NO' ELSE 'YES' END 'user_1',
       CASE SUM(users.user = 'user_2') WHEN 0 THEN 'NO' ELSE 'YES' END 'user_2',
       CASE SUM(users.user = 'user_3') WHEN 0 THEN 'NO' ELSE 'YES' END 'user_3'
  FROM (
        SELECT FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(`date`) -MOD(TO_DAYS(`date`) -1, 7)) week_beginning,
               id_user
          FROM `data`
         GROUP BY FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(`date`) -MOD(TO_DAYS(`date`) -1, 7)), id_user
       ) summary
 JOIN users ON summary.id_user = users.id
GROUP BY summary.week_beginning
ORDER BY summary.week_beginning
```

Because of the general inflexibility of this kind of pivot query, you may prefer to do this pivoting in some sort of report program instead.